# How can i insert current date in robomongo?

Tags: java, mongodb, robo3t

I want to add a date field in mongo db. I am using robo mongo. How can i do that?

If it is a string we can do it by "", if it is a number we can do it by NumberInt. What is the datatype for date field? Also, how can I insert current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.yourcollection.insert({date_field_name:new Date()})`

Comment: How can I insert any date other than current date?

Comment: var date = new Date(); and you modify "date" variable before inserting. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp  // db.yourcollection.insert({date_field_name:d})